# Upgrade to latest kernel in WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.3 in Windows 11. In Windows 11 I have enabled "Receive updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows". If I run 'wsl --update', it says I already have the latest kernel. Currently the kernel is `5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2`, but this version was released in Feb 2023 based on what I see in https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/tags.

Am I using the latest released kernel for WSL2? If not, how to install the latest kernel? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel#build-instructions ?

Answer (score 1):

From this [AskUbuntu Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/1406652/1210606) you should understand:

> Keep in mind that Ubuntu on WSL2 is really running inside a VM that you don't have access to (the "Virtual Machine Platform" feature in Windows). This VM is what provides the kernel, and then Ubuntu is run in a "namespace" inside that VM. If you were to install 18.04, 20.04, and 22.04 in WSL2, they'd all use the same WSL2 kernel rather than the stock Ubuntu kernels.

The kernel you have is equivalent to the LTS kernel of the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS release. In a "normal" Ubuntu 22.04 installation you can opt-in to the newer HWE (HardWare Enablement) stack but in WSL/WSL2 you're limited to the kernels published by Microsoft.

Comment: Yet today (2023-10-16) [Microsoft's Linux kernel repository's Makefile](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/blob/linux-msft-wsl-5.15.y/Makefile) shows version 5.15.133.1 (changed 2 weeks ago) rather than OP's 5.15.90.1 . Doesn't mean it's really available as binary though.

Comment: Does it mean that 5.15.90.1 is still the latest binary WSL2 kenrel released by Microsoft? If 5.15.133.1 is the latest version, why hasn't the binary kernel package been released?

Comment: @ChanganAuto You didn't answer my question. Is 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2  the latest released kernel for WSL2? If not, how to install the latest kernel?

Comment: Otherwise just do the usual full update of the OS - `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` and you'll get there as soon as it is available.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't agree with your answer and your comment, they don't make any sense and aren't seem to be related to my question. I run apt update and upgrade every day, but just to install update packages provided by Ubuntu. You'll never get any WSL2 kernel update by running apt commands because WSL2 kernel is not from Ubuntu, it's from Microsoft. If you run `dpkg -l | grep linux` you'll see that there's no kernel package installed in WSL2, and you'll see nothing in /boot. Please correct it if you down voted my question, because my question is valid and clearly stated.